# How to alter query of services module

Tags: 7, services, database

I am using [`service module 7.x-3.12`](https://www.drupal.org/project/services). The index call by node resource provides provides node related data but only from node table. I can't fetch the value from custom fields of a node. So I want to alter the query in index call build by `services_resource_build_index_query()` function. But I can't find any way to alter the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rules for this to add custom field or you can use "hook_services_request_postprocess_alter" to add new array with custom field.

Using rule you can set in **event** "Content is viewed of type .." and in **action** you need to custom php that returns $node->custom_field = val;

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`hook_query_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7) to alter any query that uses Drupal's database API.

Example from the docs:

```
function hook_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  if ($query->hasTag('micro_limit')) {
    $query->range(0, 2);
  }
}
```